# My Python script will not run correctly on the IDLE launcher. Can someone see if it works on there system, or check if I have a error?

Tags: python

Here is my code. I have been learning to code on Treehouse and the code seems to work as intended on their workspace. But when I try to run the script using the IDLE launcher I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jasonladieu/Desktop/Computer_number_game.py", line 48, in <module>
    com_random_number_game(1, 10)
  File "/Users/jasonladieu/Desktop/Computer_number_game.py", line 31, in com_random_number_game
    try_again()
  File "/Users/jasonladieu/Desktop/Computer_number_game.py", line 4, in try_again
    again = input("Would you like to play again?\n")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

Can someone help me figure this out. I'm kind of new to coding so if this is something simple please be gentle.

```
import random

def try_again():
    again = input("Would you like to play again?\n")
    again = str(again.upper())
    if again == "YES":
        return com_random_number_game(1, 10)
    else:
        quit()



def com_random_number_game(a, b):
    guess = random.randint(a, b)
    print("Welcome to the number guessing game.")
    user_num = input("Enter a number between " + str(a) + " and " + str(b) + " for the computer to guess.\n")
    user_num = int(user_num)

    if guess == user_num:
        print("The computer guessed your number! The computer guessed " + str(guess) + ".")
        try_again()
    if guess < user_num:
        low_guess = guess + 1
        print("The computer guessed lower than your number. The computer guessed " + str(guess) + ". Time to guess again!\n")
        guess_two = random.randint(low_guess, b)
        if guess_two == user_num:
            print("The computer guessed your number! The computer guessed " + str(guess_two) + ".")
            try_again()
        else:
            print("The computer did not guess your number. The computer guessed " + str(guess_two) + ".")
            try_again()
    if guess > user_num:
        high_guess = guess - 1
        print("The computer guessed higher than your number. The computer guessed " + str(guess) + ". Time to guess again!\n")
        guess_two = random.randint(a, high_guess)
        if guess_two == user_num:
            print("The computer guessed your number! The computer guessed " + str(guess_two) + ".")
            try_again()
        else:
            print("The computer did not guess your number. The computer guessed " + str(guess_two) + ".")
            try_again()

com_random_number_game(1, 10)
```

Comment: You're trying to run a Python 3 script in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

With Python 2.7 you need to use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) not [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input).

The last part of the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "...", line 4, in try_again
    again = input("Would you like to play again?\n")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

Is showing you that it took the string you typed in response to the prompt (from line 4), tried to run it (`<string>`, line 1) and found it was not a valid python expression. Getting practice at reading these things is very useful when learning Python. :)

Comment: Isn't raw_input() obsolete as of 3.0?

Comment: It is indeed, but based on the fact your interpreter tried to `eval()` what you gave the `input()` function, I deduce that you ran the script with Python 2 not Python 3.

Comment: interesting, I thought I had installed Python 3. I will try reinstalling it. Thank you for the help.